# Why did I get "_reactNative.AsyncStorage.setItem is not a function" error when use AsyncStorage?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using `AsyncStorage` in React Native, but my issue is always get error

> _reactNative.AsyncStorage.setItem is not a function

when I use `AsyncStorage.setItem`?

Here is some code

[image]

And the error appear :(
[image]

**UPDATE: Problem solved.**
You shouldn't name your project with the same name of any component of react-native

Comment: show your code then i can tell the problem

Comment: https://pastebin.com/6cPSYcA9
Help me @lakhvir kumar, thanks

Comment: can you share your project. everything is looking fine

Comment: waiting for upload this zip project

Comment: you can share on git or bitbucket

Comment: http://www.mediafire.com/file/nptnd5ft8vf1lfg/AsyncStorage.zip

Comment: I will upload this to git

Comment: ok wait i am checking it will inform you

Comment: @lakhvir kumar, thanks bro

Comment: may be your username state is empty thats why this is happening

Comment: your code is working fine on my side

Comment: when i set a default username state to make sure it's not empty, it's still not working :(

Comment: i am looking again will tell you if i found something wrong

Comment: wrap asynchstorage inside try catch block

Comment: thanks, this problem was solved. Since I named project with the same name of a keyword of react-native (AsyncStorage), so, when I register project and call AsyncStorage, react native will use my project instead of using AsyncStorage Component of react-native @@ :)

Comment: @lakhvir kumar, if you wrap asynchstorage inside try catch block, it's always go to catch clause :)

Comment: Good job .................

Comment: mail me @lakhvirkumar998@gmal.com or skype lakhvir777    we can help each other more

Comment: that's a good idead :)

Answer (score 1):

you should bind the function in Constructor and use JSON.stringify if you want object to store